# Make Anotations with Javascript Rickshaw

Tags: javascript, graphics, charts, rickshaw

I use RickShaw for Graphics, but I need make a few anotattion on X axis for my graphics, I use the next:

```
var annotator = new Rickshaw.Graph.Annotate({
    graph: graph,
    element: document.getElementById('timeline')
});

annotator.add(timestamp, message)
```

with rickshaw d3.v2.js.

But it doesnt work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `annotator.update()` after your `annotator.add(...)` call, see official 'annotation' example at [Rickshaw Homepage](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/), scroll down to section 'Annotations'